# Why do `kill -0 $pid; echo $?` and `ps -p$pid; echo $?` sometimes differ?

Tags: linux

I use `kill -0 $pid` (reading $pid from a PID file) to check if a daemon is running. I just discovered that even though `kill -0 2661` returns `0`, I can't see the process running in `top`, `htop` or `ps aux`. In particular, `ps -p $pid` returns `1`.

**Why is that?**

Example output:

```
$ pid=2661; kill -0 $pid; echo $?
0

$ pid=2661; ps -p $pid; echo $?
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
1
```

Same like that:

```
$ pid=2661; kill -0 $pid; echo $?; ps -p $pid; echo $?
0
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
1
```

**Edit**

It seems that this occurs more often than I thought. Here's a small snippet to check PIDs 1 to 2000 (only works as root):

```
# for pid in $(seq 1 2000); do killcode=$(kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; echo $?); pscode=$(ps -p $pid >/dev/null 2>&1; echo $?); if [ $killcode != $pscode ]; then echo $pid $killcode $pscode; fi done
820 0 1
821 0 1
822 0 1
974 0 1
977 0 1
1029 0 1
1030 0 1
...
```

Comment: Well, in that second example it looks as if pid 2661 did not exist, so one would expect to see a non-zero return from `ps`.  Maybe the process had not exited at the time you ran `kill -0`?

Comment: Unfortunately not: `$ pid=2661; kill -0 $pid; echo $?; ps -p $pid; echo $?
0
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ayecee** in #linux on Freenode answered my question. If `$pid` is a running **thread**, `kill -0 $pid` will return 0, while `ps -p $pid` will return 1.

I have verified this answer by manually picking a thread PID from `htop` and then running the above mentioned commands.